# Is Method overloading allowed across the classes? Please explain why and how?

Tags: java, overloading

My Code:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello World!");
       B b = new B();
       b.p();
   }
}

class A{
   void p(){
      System.out.println("A");
   }
}

class B extends A{
    void p(int a){
      System.out.println("B :"+a);
    }
}
```

Is method overloading allowed across the classes? Because this is working in Java. According to concepts I highly doubt this as in C++ and C# gives error but java compiler invokes correct version of function which is not expected.

Please explain why and how ?

Comment: Your test proves it is allowed. Why is it? Because it is convenient for [tag:OOP].

Comment: C++ and Java are different languages, so they behave differently. In particular, methods are non-virtual by default in C++, and _always_ virtual (except for static and private methodsl) in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Yes overloading works here because class `B` inherits the overloaded method from class `A`. This is specified in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be *overloaded*.

Answer (score 1):

In this program, When p() is called by using the object of B class, it will invoke the p() of A class as p() present in B class is having p() with integer parameter, which is not matching with the calling p().

Then it will search p() with no parameter inside the  A class and it will find the p() with same signeture, so it will execute p() of A class.

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling the method from an instance of Class B object, the method in class B would be called, if you are calling it from a method from an object of class A, even if its a class B wrapped in class A, the class A's method would be called instead